# Como fazer upload de um arquivo pelo GitHub Dev?

Tags: github

Eu recentemente estou editando os meus arquivos pelo [GitHub Dev](https://github.dev/github/dev), porém eu quero adicionar novos arquivos que está no meu computador ao meu repositório e não encontro um atalho para isso, existe alguma forma de adicionar arquivos (upload) direto por lá no meu repositório?

Comment: Como o GitHub Dev é usado para editar o código de um repositório, acredito que não é possível, e nem faz sentido, a ideia é justamente ter um ambiente de desenvolvimento 100% web. O meio de fazer isso seria fazer um commit com os arquivos para o repositório

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível fazer isso pela interface gráfica, seguindo os passos:

1. menu > file > open file...
2. clicar em open files...
3. Show local

Seguir o fluxo conforme as imagens abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao ver esta mensagem, deve-se clicar em `open files`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois vai aparecer um prompt para você selecionar o arquivo do sistema de arquivos da máquina que está utilizando.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois basta selecionar o arquivo desejado que ele aparecerá na interface do GitHub Dev

Comment: Valeu mesmo! Ajudou demais :)